# Camaleon CMS: undefined method `host' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, camaleon

When I decorate a post and then call the method `the_url()`, the following exception is thrown:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `host' for nil:NilClass

This only happens when I call the method, while performing a rake task, and when the rails app is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please include this in your task:
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
Sample:

`namespace :data do
    desc 'Print posts url'
    task sample: :environment do
        include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
        Cama::Post.all.decorate.each do |p|
            puts p.the_url
        end
    end
end`

Regards!